# Rewrite code to have BehaviorSubject subscribe with Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I am learning Angular2 and RxJS and I'm following someone else's application. In his application, he has two modules. The first is the `asObservable.ts` file:

**asObservable.ts**

```
export function asObservable(subject: Subject) {
    return new Observable(fn => subject.subscribe(fn));
}
```

The second is a file that creates a new `BehaviorSubject` RxJS object and sends it to the `asObservable.ts` module

**todo-store.service.ts**

```
import {asObservable} from "./asObservable";
import {List} from "immutable";
import {Todo} from "./todo";
// Todo is a customized class

@Injectable()
export class TodoStore {

    private _todos: BehaviorSubject<List<Todo>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));

    get todos() {
        return asObservable(this._todos);
    }

    loadInitialData() {
        this.todoBackendService.getAllTodos()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    let todos = (<Object[]>res.json()).map((todo: any) =>
                        new Todo({id:todo.id, description:todo.description, completed: todo.completed}));
                    this._todos.next(List(todos));
                },
                err => console.log("Error retrieving Todos")
            )
    }
    //unnecessary code omitted
 }
```

I would like to eliminate the `asObservable.ts` file and perform the subscribe function in a single function but I can't figure out how it would be done, something like:

```
get todos() {
    return new Observable(Subject.subscribe(this._todos));
}
```

This obviously doesn't work. Could someone give me some pointers on the proper way to do this and a brief explanation of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `return this._todos.asObservable();`?

Comment: @HarryNinh My apologies, I added additional code which shows this._todos.next() and in order to do this, I would need to subscribe. This is part of the goal is to create an Observable AND subscribe. Would `this._todos.asObservable()` still work?

Comment: Still don't understand your point. If you `subscribe` to `this._todos.asObservable()`, you WILL receive update whenever `this._todos.next(...)` is called.

Comment: Okay, just making sure. New to Observables and Angular 2. I didn't know if I had to subscribe AFTER making an Observable. I will test this and see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: It should be mentioned that a subject *is* an observable and it would work without asObservable at all (if an observable has to be public, it is preferable to have `todos$` observable counterpart for private `_todos` subject).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the original author didn't know there's already [`asObservable()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L117) method. However, his version that requires a `Subject` doesn't make sense to me, it's just a complicated way to do a very simple thing. Also, this way you can't unsubscribe.

I'd instead stick to the original `asObservable()`. Its purpose is to hide the fact that you're using a `Subject` internally and you can expose just an Observable:

```
export class TodoStore {
    // ...
    observable: Observable;

    constructor() {
        this.observable = this._todos.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then subscribing works like anywhere else:

```
let store = // ... TodoStore from DI or whatever
store.observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't know there was an `.asObservable()` method. I've been learning Angular 2 and Typescript for about a month and there's a lot to take in.